# How to reference to matplotlib.animation with tk.button?

Tags: python, animation, matplotlib, tkinter

I have solved my first problem how to call FuncAnimation from inside a function with the help of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21099121/python-matplotlib-unable-to-call-funcanimation-from-inside-a-function).

The answer was to return `ani` and to  keep a reference to it in the code:

```
def a(...):
    # stuff
    ani = animation.FuncAnimation(...)
    # more stuff
    return ani

outer_ani = a(...)
```

In this example the reference is in the code immediately but I want to reference to it after a click on a `tkinter.Button()`.

How could I solve this problem?
Putting this reference into another function and to call this one with the Button doesn't work.

Thanks for your help!

*(I am sorry for my awful English and my stupid and vague question but I don't know how to describe it more deatailed.)*

Edit:
This is my (shortened, simplified) code:

```
    root = tk.Tk()
    def a():
        fig = Figure(figsize=(4.1,8.2)) 

        def init():
            ax.set_ylim(-50, 50)
            ax.set_xlim(-50, 50)
            #more stuff

        def update(f):           
            y=50-f
            x=0
            ln.set_xdata(x)
            ln.set_ydata(y)
            return ln,

        diacan2 = FigureCanvasTkAgg(fig,master=root)
        diacan2.get_tk_widget().place(x=680,y=20)
        diacan2.show()        

        ax = fig.add_subplot(2,1,1)
        bx = fig.add_subplot(2,1,2)
        x, y = [], []
        ln, = ax.plot([], [], 'ro', animated=True) 
        ani = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, update, init_func=init, frames=100, interval=30, blit=True, repeat=False)

##################################################

tk.Button(master=root, text="bla", command=a())
```

Answer (score 0):

The other answer kept the variable as a global, which I would disagree with. I recommend you keep the reference as an attribute to something. If you designed your GUI code correctly, then simply make it an instance variable:

```
def a(...):
    # stuff
    self.ani = animation.FuncAnimation(...)
```

Otherwise add it as an attribute to your tkinter window or anything that is used as long as the program is running:

```
def a(...):
    # stuff
    root.ani = animation.FuncAnimation(...)
```

I'd have to see the rest of your code to give you a more complete answer.