# Matplotlib FuncAnimation fails to run and is bypassed in tkinter GUI

Tags: python, multithreading, matplotlib, tkinter, scatter

I am trying to have two daemonic threads run alongside my tkinter main thread. One of the threads generates data and the other thread runs FuncAnimation that plots the data that is generated. However, I am having issues with getting FuncAnimation to run, I can see that whenever I click the button both print statements are shown in the console meaning FuncAnimation appears to have been skipped or ran but exited due to some missing or bad parameter. I checked the matplotlib documentation to ensure I'm not missing anything and I think I have created all the objects and called the right methods to make this happen but something is obviously amiss. Any help is greatly appreciated.

```
import tkinter as tk
import time
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import (FigureCanvasTkAgg, NavigationToolbar2Tk)
from matplotlib.figure import Figure
from matplotlib import animation
import threading



root = tk.Tk()




class dynamicChart():
    
    def __init__(self):
        
        self.x = []
        self.y = []
        self.buildChart()
        
    def buildChart(self):
        
        self.figure = Figure(figsize=(5, 5), dpi=100)
        ax = self.figure.add_subplot(111)
        self.scatter = ax.scatter(self.x,self.y)

        canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(self.figure, root)
        canvas.draw()
        canvas.get_tk_widget().pack(pady=10)
        
        toolbar = NavigationToolbar2Tk(canvas, root)
        toolbar.update()
        canvas.get_tk_widget().pack()


    def animate(self,i):
        print("Enter animate")
        self.scatter.set_offsets([self.x, self.y])
    
    def Ani(self):
        print("Enter Ani")
        self.animation = animation.FuncAnimation(self.figure, self.animate, interval = 2000)
        print("Exit Ani")
        
        
class genData():
    
    def __init__(self):
        
        self.chart = dynamicChart()
        
    def generate(self):
        X = 2
        Y = 2
        i = 1
        while True:
            
            time.sleep(1)
            
            X = X*i
            Y = Y + i
    
            self.chart.x.append(X)
            self.chart.y.append(Y)
            
            i+=1
    
StartDataGen_CreateFigureAxes = genData()

genData = threading.Thread(target = StartDataGen_CreateFigureAxes.generate, daemon  = True)
genData.start()

ani = threading.Thread(target = StartDataGen_CreateFigureAxes.chart.Ani, daemon  = True)


button = tk.Button(root, text="Graph It", command = lambda: ani.start())
button.pack()
  
    

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Probably the issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21099121/python-matplotlib-unable-to-call-funcanimation-from-inside-a-function

The FuncAnimation call doesn't block, it makes the animation object and immediately moves on. So when the function exits, the object loses its 1 reference and is garbage collected. Try returning the animation and keeping it alive by assigning it to a variable, attribute, or element of a container.

Comment: @BatWannaBe It is assigned as an attribute of the dynamicChart() class, would that not prevent it from being garbage collected?

Comment: yes, actually, I must've overlooked it.