# pyplot doesn't animate when starting image doesn't have variation

Tags: python, matplotlib, animation

I am trying out a code in which I want the plot to be all purple most of the times, then flash a corner yellow for a fraction of second.

Here is my code for the same.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.animation as animation
import random 

fig = plt.figure()
first = True
c = 0
x = 10
y = 10

def generateBoard(x, y):
    global c
    global first
    board = np.zeros([x,y])

    ### Code Snippet
    if first:
        board[0,0] = 1
        first = False
    ###

    if c <10:
        c=c+1
    else:
        board[0:2,0:2] = 1      ##Snippet 2
        c=0

    return board

im = plt.imshow(generateBoard(x, y), animated=True)

def updatefig(*args):
    im.set_array(generateBoard(x, y))
    return im,

ani = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, updatefig, interval=90, blit=True)
plt.show()
```

The code doesn't animate my plot without the code snippet of `first`. Though the code works fine, but I want to understand the cause of this behavior

Comment: You need to set `vmin=` and `vmax=` to have a consistent color range, e.g. `imgshow(..., vmin=0, vmax=1)`.

Comment: Also see the second answer (by @tacaswell, matplotlib's lead developer) in [Show consecutive images/arrays with imshow as repeating animation in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18743673/show-consecutive-images-arrays-with-imshow-as-repeating-animation-in-python)